# Binding DependencyProperty to non-DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a usercontrol from winforms. In the XAML I am trying to bind a dependency property to one of the usercontrol's property as below (which is not a dependency property)

```
<Pricing:UserControl1  UserControlProperty="{Binding CurrentProductItem.ComponentId}"  />
```

I am getting an error A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'UserControlProperty' property of type 'UserControl1'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. How I can solve this issue? Do I need to make UserControlProperty as dependencyproperty?

Comment: In WPF binding only works on dependency property so you will have to make the UserControlProperty as dependency property.

Comment: @jadavparesh06, since it is from winforms usercontrol, any idea to convert it?

Comment: You can solve this by creating a WPF UserControl that wraps your UserControl1 . You can then add a WPFUserControlProperty dependency property to your UserControl. In the property changed handler of this dependency property, set the WPFUserControlProperty property on the UserControl's UserControlProperty that this user control wraps.

Comment: Yap, long way, bt can :-)