# WPF usercontrol click event handling

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a WPF usercontrol which contains the Winforms usercontrol. Winform usercontrol contains a picturebox.  My requirement is to capture the click event on WPF usercontrol. I have tried with             `PreviewMouseDown="ImageUserControl_MouseDown" and MouseDown="img1_MouseDown"` events in the WPF usercontrol to capture the event. Nothing worked out.

Anyhow inside the winform usercontrol If I added a click event, it works. Do I need to route it up to WPF usercontrol level?

Please let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: Any specific reason you're using a PictureBox instead of a WPF `Image` control?

Comment: @HighCore reason is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270453/binding-dependencyproperty-to-non-dependencyproperty

Comment: that doesn't explain anything. Why are you using a winforms `UserControl` then?

Comment: @HighCore, please check the comments, I am binding non Dependency property to a Dependency property. The non dependency property come from winforms usercontrol. It is wrapped into a WPF usercontrol and then it is binded.

Comment: I still fail to understand why is winforms in between, bothering you with it's incapabilities. Do you really need the winforms part? What's in it that can't be done directly in WPF?

Comment: @HighCore I need to load wmf and emf files to the Picturebox. WPF Image does not support EMF/WMF, so I have used WinForms Picturebox.

Comment: @HighCore, Have you understood my point?

Comment: yes. In that case, you're better off handling the winforms click events manually.